# TeXnicCenter and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter as an editor to run LaTeX files. But when using package `\usepackage{glossaries}`, it doesn't display glossary list as it is supposed.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{foobar}{%
 name={Foobar},
 description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foo}}
 }

 \newglossaryentry{foo}{%
 name={Foo},
 description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foobar}}
 }

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\gls{foobar} is a strange animal

\gls{foo} is another strange animal
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

As a precaution, I upload a screenshot of TeXnicCenter profiles in case if it asked

[image: profile]

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` on the `.tex` file? Alternatively, you could also add the `automake` option to the `glossaries` package.

Comment: @leandriis Oh thanks, I have added `automake` and it does work. Anyway. What did you mean by saying running `makeglossaries`?

Comment: @MuhammedHashim See [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `makeindex` for generation of your glossary you should have a look to chapter 1.5.4  Using makeindex explicitly (Option 2) in the documentation of glossaries (`texdoc glossaries` in your console/terminal).

After the first compile run of your given file, let us name it `mwe.tex` you will find some new files in the directory `mwe.tex` is: `mwe.ist`, `mwe.glo`

Now you need to run `makeindex` as mentioned in the documentation with

```
makeindex -s〈style〉.ist -t〈base〉.glg -o〈base〉.gls〈base〉.glo
```

in your case that means you need command

```
makeindex -s mwe.ist -t mwe.glg -o mwe.gls mwe.glo
```

Now copy your standard profile `LaTEX -> PDF` to a new one, for example `LaTeX glos->PDF`.  There you change the **Command line arguments to pass to `makeindex`** to

```
-s "%tm.ist" -t "%tm.glg" -o "%tm.gls" "%tm.glo"
```

Do not forget to click on "Ok" to change the new profile permanently.

[image: profile]

No compile again. You can see that `makeindex` had be run with the given parameters, because you got now two files `mwe.gls` and `mwe.glg`

Compile two times again to get all TOC etc. printed as you can see in the following image:

[image: result]

But please see that you have to change this profile for TeXnicCenter if there are major changings in using /building your glossaries, for example if you want to build two glossaries. I guess adding option `automake` is easier to handle ...

Comment: For multiple glossaries it's simpler to use `makeglossaries` (Perl) or `makeglossaries-lite` (Lua) which will pick up all the file extensions and indexing settings from the `.aux` file instead of calling `makeindex` directly.